# PHP ignores values with spaces in <select> box

Tags: php

i have a select box which show list of company name & the code for that is like below.

```
echo "<option value=$getClient[company_name]>$getClient[company_name]</option>";
```

the thing is if

```
<option value=$getClient[company_name]>
```

has something like Abcd Company
as it's value after submit, it only shows the part "Abcd". lines after space been left out. but on the database where i store the data it appears as "Abcd Company" when i try to view data through a frontend this thing happens.

can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you show more of your PHP code, and possibly some of the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 7):

The value of `value` (pun intended) should be encapsulated in quotes (`value=a b` is not valid, `value="a b"` is).

Also, make sure to defend against [Cross-Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

```
echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($getClient['company_name']) . '">';
echo htmlspecialchars($getClient['company_name']);
echo '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

when you echo it out, it will look something like this...

```
<tagName attribute=property with spaces>
```

So the words `with spaces` are treated as other attributes in HTML. You need to add quotes around the property value like this:

```
echo "<option value='$getClient[company_name]'>$getClient[company_name]</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks ppl you guys save the day.

Answer (score 0):

PHP don't ignores it. Really PHP don't get it!

`value=x y` is interpreted as `value=x` and property `y` without value.
You should use qoutes to show browser what is correct atribute value

Answer (score -1):

use trim function to remove white space.

Comment: trim don't delete whitespaces inside string

Comment: @RiaD trim **doesn't** delete whitespace characters inside the string